# jQuery .click() method doesn't work with .attr("src") = " "

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple code: an html document that will take the values inserted in a testbox and an area box and create a comment section with the person's name and comment. The name will have a [+] image next to it (yes, it has to be an image due to paper demands) that when clicked will turn into a [-] image and display the hidden comment. I wrote the following text:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="name"/>Enter your name here <br />
    <textarea id="message"></textarea>
    <button onclick="message()">Submit message</button>
    <span id="anchor"></span>
<script>
        function message() { //Built by Nimrod Yanai as an example.
            var name = $("#name").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var name2 = '<div><p><img class=\"pic\" src=\"Plus.jpg\">' + name + '</p><br /><p class=\"hide message\">' + message + '</p></div>';
            $(name2).insertBefore("#anchor");
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('body').on('click', ".pic", function () {
                if ($(this).attr("src") == "Plus.jpg") {
                    $(this).attr("src", "Minus.jpg");
                    $(".message").removeClass("hide");
                }
                else {
                    $(this).attr("src", "Plus.jpg");
                    $(".message").addClass("hide");
                }
            });
        });

</script>
</body>
```

The code is supposedly very simple... But it doesn't work.
Using F12 I confirmed that the relevant s are created, with all the proper classes and ids. I inserted a name and comment into the test page and indeed a written name was displayed with a [+] img before it. When I remove the CSS I can see that the second div with the value of the textarea is indeed created corretly as well. So I assume the first function works perfectly.

The problem starts with the second function, as pressig the img element does nothing.

Here's what I've tried so far: 
1. Creating an  element before the picture and moving the id="pic" to that. Didn't work.
2. Placing an [+] text instead of the picture within an  element to see if that works, but it didn't.

Any thoughts as to how I can solve this? It should've been very simple...

P.S.
The F12 doesn't show any errors on the page when I press the picture, it simply does nothing.

Comment: `if ($("#pic").attr("src") = "Plus.jpg")` is an assignment, not a comparison. Also, why are you escaping quotes in the name2 variable line?

Comment: the img is being added dynamically so you should use .on() to add events to it instead of .click() directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

```
$('body').on('click', '.pic', function(){
  if ($(this).attr("src") == "Plus.jpg") {
    $(this).attr("src", "Minus.jpg");
    $(this).closest('div').find(".message").removeClass("hide");
  } else {
    $(this).attr("src", "Plus.jpg");
    $(this).closest('div').find(".message").addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

---

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like the below instead of click on image#pic directly as it is being added dynamically.

Also, as user @j08691 mentioned in the comments, you are using as assignment operator in the if condition.

```
$('body').on('click', "#pic", function() {
  if ($("#pic").attr("src") == "Plus.jpg") {
    $("#pic").attr("src", "Minus.jpg");
    $(".message").removeClass("hide");
  } else {
    $("#pic").attr("src", "Plus.jpg");
    $(".message").addClass("hide");
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click', "#pic", function() {
    if ($("#pic").attr("src") == "Plus.jpg") {
      $("#pic").attr("src", "Minus.jpg");
      $(".message").removeClass("hide");
    } else {
      $("#pic").attr("src", "Plus.jpg");
      $(".message").addClass("hide");
    }
  });
});

function message() {
  var name = $("#name").val();
  var message = $("#message").val();
  var name2 = '<div><p><img id=\"pic\" src=\"Plus.jpg\">' + name + '</p><br /><div class=\"hide message\"><p>' + message + '</p></div></div>';
  $(name2).insertBefore("#anchor");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />Enter your name here
<br />
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<button onclick="message()">Submit message</button>
<span id="anchor"></span>
```

Comment: Of course, such a silly thing like = instead of ==... Those always get me!

Thanx, it works perfecly now.

Comment: #Dhiraj Bodicherla
Now I've encountered another issue: because of the way I wrote the code, now each time I press the [+] or [-] buttons, ALL of them toggleClass (because all of them have the "message" class... I changed all the #pic to (this) so it'll only apply to the specific pic I'm pressing, but that only prevents the [+] from changing in all of them, obviously.
How do I add something to make it only choose the next div? I thought of using something like .children() but the div isn't a child of the img element...

Comment: first of all you cannot have multiple IDs so change it to class. Also, if you have multiple of instances of those [+][-] stuff, please update the question along with an example so that solving would be easier

Comment: I've updated the code to show the changes I made (id to class, pic to $(this), etc.) but it's basically the same.
The HTML has an anchor at the bottom, and each time the button is pressed, a new div with the name and comment is created above it and it gets pushed down, so that each time the next comment will appear below the previous.
The question is, how do I use $(this) on the specific divs, if they are not the ones I press? I need to connect them to the img element somehow, but how? .parent()? .children()?

Comment: I tried using:
                    $(this).parent.next.removeClass("hide");
and:
                    $(this).parent.next.addClass("hide");
i.e. to choose the next <p> after the <p> which is the parent of $(this), but that doesn't seem to work...